# Is there any way to create a folder in the already existing S3 bucket thorugh python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, s3-bucket

In the documentation of boto3 there is no function to do make a directory in the bucket. Although we can add the folder manually but I need some code to do through python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create folders in S3.

If you create an object with the key `pics/cats/funny.gif`, the "folder" `cats` will automatically appear inside the "folder" `pics`.

The word "folder" is in quotes because folders are not containers in S3.  They are derived for display from the `/` delimiters in the object keys.

If you want to see empty folders, you can create empty objects (containing 0 bytes, an empty string) with names **ending** in `/` such as `pics/` or `pics/cats/` but these serve no real purpose other than allowing you to see them in the console while they are "empty."

S3 technically stores your objects in a flat lexical index space, not in a hierarchy.  The console will organize objects with `/` in their names into visible folders, automatically.

This is explained in [Working with Folders](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html).